# in IE mustache thinks the template tag is eq(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, mustache

I'm trying to query `.eq(N)`, but it's all off by one in IE because IE thinks that the `<template>` tag is `eq(0)`.

How do I get the expected output where the template tag is ignored so `$('h1').eq(0).attr("id")` is the first generated element in #output, not the element in the `<template>` tag ?

For example

JSON:

```
   var myJSON = {"id" : 80,"name" : "Frank"};
```

HTML:

```
<template style='display:none' id='myTemplate'>
  <h1 id='header{{id}}'>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</template>
<div id='output'></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#output').append( Mustache.render($('#myTemplate').html(), myJSON));
```

In IE:

```
console.log($('h1').eq(0).attr("id")); //header{{id}}
```

Everywhere else:

```
console.log($('h1').eq(0).attr("id")); //header80
```

Comment: It would probably help if you'd `console.log($("#myTemplate").html())`

Comment: hmm... to me i'd say IE is doing it correctly here. the first h1 is the one within the template. I suggest using an element what would contain content that won't be parsed as html, such as a script tag with a custom type value.

Comment: The `template` element is *currently* not supported in Internet Explorer, so I wouldn't be shocked if it behaves differently across browsers. [You can vote](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6261273-template-element) for the IE team to ship support for it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<template style='display:none' id='myTemplate'>` I used `<script type='x-tmpl-mustache' id='myTemplate'>`. The template tag isn't supported in IE http://caniuse.com/#search=template. Thanks for the heads up @Jonathan Sampson, I voted too.